# Access Report, get value from parent report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a report.  Within that report is a sub report.  And, there's a sub report within the first sub report. Anyway, each report has a stored query as its data source.  The structure looks like this:

> - Main Report
>
>   - Sub Report 1
>
>     - Sub Report 2

I would like the stored query in Sub Report 2 to reference a field in Sub Report1.  But, every time I run the report, I get a message box asking for the value.  Here is the bit in my query that references the field:

```
[Reports]![MainReport]![SubReport1]!Report![Text70].value
```

Anyone know the correct syntax?

Comment: Change third exclamation point to a period: `[Reports]![MainReport]![SubReport1].Report![Text70].value`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that still did not help.

Comment: I didn't express the problem correctly.  Let me edit it.

Comment: The report may not be loaded before recordsource query processes. Try using a `DLookUp()` to first subreport's recordsource to find value bound to `[Text70]`. Does subreport2's stored query run ok when report is opened in report view?

Comment: Do you mean, run the report, then run the query?  If so, no, I get the same dialog asking for the value

Comment: Possible cause: `[SubReport1]` must be the name of the subreport control on `Main Report`, not the name of "Sub Report 1". Usually they are identical, but not necessarily.

Comment: I checked the names.  They are correct.  I essentially, I just want to know how to reference once control in a subreport, from another sub reports.  Both in the same main report.

Comment: Not sure why, but leaving of "value" seems to have done it.  So, just something like: [Reports]![MainReport]![SubReport1]!Report![Text70] works

Comment: one problem that took me a long time to realise is that if you change your form name in the navigation window and forgets to change the "sub-form" name on your report, you can spend hours trying to figure out why the reference was incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but leaving off `value` seems to have done it.

So, just something like: `[Reports]![MainReport]![SubReport1]!Report![Text70]` works.